# How do I get to any id number in a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays

My nested array below:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'category_name' => 'Vehicle',
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 4,
      'category_name' => 'Bmw',
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 5,
        'category_name' => 'Mercedes',
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 6,
          'category_name' => 'Bmw X7',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'category_name' => 'TV',
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8,
      'category_name' => 'Led TV',
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 9,
        'category_name' => 'Philips',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'category_name' => 'Phone',
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 10,
      'category_name' => 'Samsung',
    ),
  ),
)
```

My code below:

```
public function index($id)
{

$categories= array(
            array('id' => 1 , 'category_name' => 'Vehicle', array('id' => 4 , 'category_name' => 'Bmw',array('id' => 5 , 'category_name' => 'Mercedes' , array('id' => 6 , 'category_name' => 'Bmw X7')))),
            array('id' => 2 , 'category_name' => 'TV', array('id' => 8 , 'category_name' => 'Led TV' , array('id' => 9 , 'category_name' => 'Philips'))),
            array('id' => 3 , 'category_name' => 'Phone' , array('id' => 10 , 'category_name' => 'Samsung'))
        );
    foreach ($categories as $row)
          {
              if($row['id'] == $id)
              {
                 $parent_category = $row;
                 break;
              }
          }
}
```

I can reach the first array id values. I want to get the id values inside.I look forward to your help and thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share your actual `array`? like `var_dump` or  `print_r` output , this is unreadable on `php`

Comment: No @Mrx better with `var_export`, that can be copy pasted unlike print_r or var_dump.

Comment: dose you array structure will change? like more nested ids can be come. Or  array structure will be identical in all cases?

Comment: infinite series.

Comment: your question is truly unclear. please be move specific and expressive about what your question and what excatly you expect your code to do

Comment: BTW, i believe array_walk_recursive will be handy for what you are looking for, or try to write a recursion function if you want

Comment: @ufuk What result do you want to get - index of subarray with that id in array or full subarray?

Comment: Any id in array but i solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, I figured out what you want, You need another `foreach` loop inside the first one:

```
foreach ($categories as $row) {
echo $row["id"];
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["id"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Has failed in the second foreach loop.  Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: I've shared above bro.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem as follows:

```
    $result   = array();
    $search   = 'id';
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator(
            $categories,
            RecursiveArrayIterator::CHILD_ARRAYS_ONLY
        )
    );

    foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($search==$key && $value!=='')
        {
            if($value == 10){
                $result[] = array($key => $value);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```